# Upload images and inserting it as blob into database sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-2.7, sqlite

I am creating my first GUI software, I need to know How to create a function that allows users to upload pictures from their system and insert them into the database.

Comment: and what is the problem? It is not clear what makes problem and we can't answer for this question. And you didn't say what GUI framework you use. Normally you ask user for filename and you use can use standard `open()`, `read()` to get data, and later you can put it in database.

Comment: furas, thanks for your response, it Tkinter, the problem solved.